# generating multiple files from one file

Tags: java, file, split

I have a text file (tab seperated and new lines for rows) having n columns . I want to split that file on forth column  and generate one file for each distinct value of that column.

i.e if five rows have same column value say X , all these five rows would go in x.txt and so on.

At the end of the processing , I will have m files if there are m distinct values in column four. You can assume that column 4 is of "Date" type. So essentially need to partition data on date column and generate different files with each file having data for a specified date.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Is this going to be a one-time thing? If so, I would suggest you use any text editor that allows column based selection.

Comment: No. This is going to be a repeatitive task so I want to write a java program for it.

Comment: load file into a database :) and dump it as you like :). but in normal ways you load your file into an arraylist<YourRowObject> you create class which `implements Comparator<YourRowObject>` and compare dates of your row there then. do `Collections.sort(arraylist,comparatorInstance);` then iterate and do whatever you like with it.

Comment: If you have to do more and similar tasks you could consider using fmpp, which is a frontend for the freemarker template engine and can do outputfile spliting based on input. s. http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

A simple draft

```
public static void main( String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] input = {"A1\tB\tC\tD\t2012-02-10",
        "A2\tB\tC\tD\t2012-02-10",
        "A3\tB\tC\tD\t2012-02-08",
        "A4\tB\tC\tD\t2012-02-08",
        "A5\t\tC\tD\t2012-02-07",
        "A6\tB\tC\tD\t2012-02-07" };

    Map<String,String> map = new  HashMap<String, String>();
    for ( String row : input ) {
        String[] cols = row.split( "\t" );
        String date = cols[4];
        String content = map.get( date );
        content = (content == null) ? row : content + "\n" + row;
        map.put( date, content );
    }
    for ( String filename : map.keySet() ) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\" + filename );
        fos.write( map.get( filename ).getBytes() );
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Note: You shold use correct line separator char and encoding.

For reading the input you could use [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/)

Answer (score 0):

In the solution provided by stacker, you may use `java.util.Scanner` to read input file as follows:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("YourFilePath"));
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
     String row = scanner.nextLine();
     .......
}
```